# Sencha Touch - Tab Panel Layout

Tags: sencha-touch, tabpanel

Please see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/NGrry/1/

[image]

How to make content of tab panel fill the center area? The heading should be on the top, below toolbar.

Expected layout: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/. I think the Source isn't complete, only the tabPanel itself.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to do that sort of layout I've had to nest panels and use empty panels with the flex attribute set to 1.

I adjusted your code to show what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/r9c2M/

For example to center the text 'Home' underneath the toolbar title I changed the first tabpanel item to

```
{
    title: 'Home',
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {layout: 'hbox',
         items: [
            {flex: 1},
            {html: '<h2>Home</h2>'},
            {flex: 1}
        ]},
        {flex: 1}
    ],
    iconCls: 'home',
    cls: 'card card1'}
```

Also the tabpanel should just be an item of the main viewport panel, not a dockedItem.  That was messing up the layout too.